# Question about flex will not fill the width of the parent container

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
.outside {
  /*  Note line3, the top and bottom will be the same, why add the flex on the different */
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
  </div>
</div>

========

<div class="content">
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
</div>
```

the screenshot is how the two cases work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyjx8.png)

Questions:

1. I don't know why the with of element with class outside do not fill the screen(like the element with class content)
2. I would like to know on what basis the 20% of item is calculated

Answer (score 1):

1. Whenever you specify `display: flex` on an element, you're inherently adding the following styling to the child elements:

```
.child {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}
```

In the top example, this gets applied to the element with class `'content'`. If you were to set `flex-grow: 1` on the style block for `.content`, you would see it take up the whole width.

2. In your current example, the `20%` width is determined from the width of the element with class `'content'`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `.content` inside `.outside`.

And you set `display: flex;` for `.outside`, which changes the width of `.content` (flex changes widths of children). It is now a single element in the flex row. If you set `width: 100%;` for `.content` it will fill that row.

```css
.outside {
  /*  Note line3, the top and bottom will be the same, why add the flex on the different */
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: skyblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">apple</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
    <div class="item">banana</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">apple</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
  <div class="item">banana</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the flex full width display please update your styles as follows;

```
.outside {
        /*  Note line3, the top and bottom will be the same, why add the flex on the different */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .content {
        background: skyblue;
        display: flex;
    }

    .item {
        width: 20%;
    }
```

Also you need to read more about flex [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use flex-grow:1 on .content as:

```
  .content {
    background: skyblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
```

This means the child will now take all the remaining space available. By default, the flex child just takes space as per its content.

You can check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-buck-mumtl3?file=/index.html